# Undefined return error coming from verifyTokenGoogle

Tags: node.js, typescript, google-cloud-platform

I'm having a problem where the `googleTokenInfo` variable, returned by Google, in a token check, can return `undefined`, so I do a conditional to do the check, but when trying to execute the endpoint, the application stops in the condition, returning the http 500 error.

```
const googleTokenInfo = await client.verifyIdToken({
            idToken: googleToken,
            audience: "********************************"
        });
                
        const user = googleTokenInfo.getPayload();
            
        if (!user) {
            throw new Error ("Non-google token.");
        }
```

The asterisk location only replaces for security purposes

Comment: Are you catching the error you're throwing here? Post the code that calls this method too

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the server cache. I reset the server and the problem was resolved.

Comment: What server cache are you referring to? Where are you running the code?